# RHRV package error while running the tutorial

Tags: r

I am trying to use `RHRV` package for creating an app. when I run the code:

```
hrv.data = LoadBeatAscii(hrv.data, "example.beats",RecordPath = "beatsFolder")
```

I get an error

> Error in setwd(RecordPath) : cannot change working directory.

What could be the issue ?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -2):

enter in "beatsfolder" then, run above command like hrv.data = LoadBeatAscii(hrv.data, "example.beats"). It worked for me.

Comment: How s/he can enter in "beatsFolder"? I have the same problem and I don´t know where is it?