# Issue loading heart rate data with RHRV Package in R MarkDown

Tags: r-markdown, heartrate

I'm having issues loading a `.txt` file in R Markdown using the `LoadBeatAscii()` function from the `RHRV` package. When I try to load from a folder it says:

**Error in setwd(RecordPath) : cannot change working directory**

**Example**

```
library(RHRV) 
hrv.data <- CreateHRVData() #This creates an empty list.object in which to load raw data into
hrv.data <- SetVerbose(hrv.data, TRUE) #to return additional information 
hrv.data <- LoadBeatAscii(hrv.data, RecordName = "beat_ascii.txt", RecordPath = "Data/beat_ascii.txt") #loading data from 'Data' folder into the hrv.data list object
```

The data that I am using in this example is available online from milegroup (it is the ascii file containing beats positions) called `beat_ascii.txt` available here: http://milegroup.github.io/ghrv/packages.html

Otherwise a small sample of the data is here:

```
c(1.036, 1.7, 2.364, 3.024, 3.668, 4.324, 4.98, 5.656, 6.312, 
6.96, 7.612, 8.248, 8.896, 9.54, 10.184, 10.824, 11.472, 12.128, 
12.776, 13.432, 14.088, 14.756, 15.424, 16.112, 16.768, 17.444, 
18.124, 18.816, 19.484, 20.164, 20.856, 21.552, 22.224, 22.9, 
23.6, 24.304, 24.968, 25.644, 26.328, 27.008, 27.68, 28.356, 
29.036, 29.696, 30.356, 31.032, 31.684, 32.344, 33, 33.66, 34.312, 
34.976, 35.644, 36.3, 36.964, 37.64, 38.308, 38.988, 39.676, 
40.348, 41.04, 41.744, 42.424, 43.1, 43.776, 44.46, 45.128, 45.808, 
46.496, 47.168, 47.808, 48.48, 49.136, 49.788, 50.44, 51.112, 
51.756, 52.412, 53.064, 53.712, 54.372, 55.028, 55.696, 56.344, 
57.008, 57.672, 58.332, 58.996, 59.652, 60.3, 60.948, 61.584, 
62.22, 62.852, 63.476, 64.096, 64.724, 65.356, 65.992, 66.628
)
```

Does anyone understand what the issue is?

**UPDATE**
Someone else has had the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390460/rhrv-package-error-while-running-the-tutorial) but no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake was naming the `.txt` file, which should be omitted from `RecordPath`:

```
hrv.data <- LoadBeatAscii(hrv.data, RecordName = "beat_ascii.txt", RecordPath = "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/Desktop/Data")
```